# How can you iterate through all select multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to check all my `<select multiple>` inputs to make sure my users make a choice.

If these inputs don't have a value, then I can add a class to create some visual reminder, but I'm not sure how to iterate through them?

I'd be happy just iterating through all the `<select>` elements, since the non-multiple ones will always have a choice made by default.

I've tried `$('input:select')`, `$('select')` to no avail.

Comment: First one is looking for `<input>` tags ...Second should work fine. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many select elements with `multiple` attribute, you can iterate through all of them:

```
$('select[multiple]').each(function() {
  // Check if at least one selection is made
  if($(this).val().length > 0) {
    console.log('selection is made');
  } else {
    console.log('no selection is made');
  }
});
```

The above solution utilizes jQuery's attribute selector to get the collection of all select elements which have `multiple` attribute assigned to them.

Also, jQuery returns an array when `.val()` is called on a select tag with `multiple` attribute. So, you can check the length of the value returned to identify if at least one selection is made or not.

Comment: Doh! makes sense now and works like a charm. Thank you!